# Dynamically created c# label not visible

Tags: c#, properties, label

I'm attempting to display some dynamically generated labels next to  dynamically generated text boxes.  The text boxes appear but the labels do not.

I've looked at several solutions and have tried to make sure I defined all the label properties.  I looked at some threading related solution that seem unnecessary because i'm not changing visibility state, I would just like to  pop up the labels next to the text boxes.

```cs
TextBox[] channelNames = new TextBox[numOfChannels];
GroupBox channelBox = new GroupBox();
Label[] labelNames = new Label[numOfChannels];

for (int currentChannelIndex = 0; currentChannelIndex < numOfChannels; currentChannelIndex++)
{
    var txt = new TextBox();
    channelNames[currentChannelIndex] = txt;
    txt.Name = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName;
    txt.Text = "ben";
    txt.Location = new Point(200, 32 + (currentChannelIndex * 28));
    txt.Visible = true;
    this.channelBox.Controls.Add(channelNames[currentChannelIndex]);

    var lbl = new Label();
    labelNames[currentChannelIndex] = lbl;
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Name = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName;
    lbl.Size = new Size(55, 13);
    lbl.TabIndex = 69;
    lbl.Text = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName;
    lbl.Location = new Point(175, 32 + (currentChannelIndex * 28));
    lbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    this.channelBox.Controls.Add(labelNames[currentChannelIndex]);
}
```

Comment: You checked if Physical Name is not an empty string

Comment: Hi yes i did check in debug and it's getting a string value input, and the same Physical Name is being used to generate the TextBox which is working.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check:

1) You are setting "AutoSize" and "Size".  Trying removing "Size"

2) The default font is likely too large for the (55,13) size.
   Try explicitly setting the font to something small to see if it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Does `channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName` actually contain a non-Empty string? e.g.:

```cs
        class Something
        {
            public string PhysicalName { get; set; }
        }

        private void AddLabels()
        {
            Something[] channelCollection = new Something[]
            {
                //Applying this to Label.Text makes it "invisible"
                new Something() { PhysicalName = "" }
            };
            var currentChannelIndex = 0;

            var txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Name = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName;
            txt.Text = "ben";
            txt.Location = new Point(200, 32);
            txt.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(txt);

            var lbl = new Label();
            lbl.AutoSize = true;
            lbl.Name = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName;
            lbl.Size = new Size(55, 13);
            lbl.TabIndex = 69;
            lbl.Text = channelCollection[currentChannelIndex].PhysicalName;
            lbl.Location = new Point(175, 32);
            lbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
```

Comment: Hi yes i did check in debug and it's getting a string value input, and the same Physical Name is being used to generate the TextBox which is working

Answer (score 0):

I actually had an exception that downstream of this code block that was causing the issue.  I assumed that i would see the labels since the exception was thrown after the call to the label.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes it is but i can't mark my own answer until tomorrow.